# Javascript/jQuery to check strings in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a working jQuery codes that have a condition to return true if it matches the name.

```
jQuery(function(j) {
    var strings = j(".user-nicename").text();  
    if (strings === "name1" ) {
       j('.mention-name').hide();  
       j('.separator').hide();
       j('.separator').hide();  
       j('.field_8263').css("display", "none");
       j('#activity-personal-li').css("display", "none");  
       j('#groups-personal-li').css("display", "none");  
  
    }
});
jQuery(function(j) {
    var strings = j(".user-nicename").text();  
    if (strings === "name2" ) {
       j('.mention-name').hide();  
       j('.separator').hide();
       j('.separator').hide();  
       j('.field_8263').css("display", "none");
       j('#activity-personal-li').css("display", "none");  
       j('#groups-personal-li').css("display", "none");  
  
    }
});
```

However, I would like to add these names in an array. But once I do that, the code is not working anymore...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var strings = $(".user-nicename").text(); 
    var authorName = ["name1" , "name2"];
    if (strings === "authorName" ) {
       $('.mention-name').hide();  
       $('.separator').hide();
       $('.separator').hide();  
       $('.field_8263').css("display", "none");
       $('#activity-personal-li').css("display", "none");  
       $('#groups-personal-li').css("display", "none");  
  
    }
});
```

Maybe anyone can help me? I think the "array" code is not correct. Thank you!

Comment: array includes....

Comment: @epascarello Care to elaborate please? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: @epascarello Although it should work but the examples are actually choosing one string in an array... The answer below by Da Mahdi03 is actually the most accurate one. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Um, the answer is what the link is.... The selected answer is not always the exact answer you are looking for in duplicates. Highly upvoted answers are normally good things to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are trying to do is add all the string into the array and then see if the string exists in the array, to do that you want

```
var strings = $(".user-nicename").text(); 
var authorName = ["name1" , "name2"];
if (authorName.includes(strings)) {
    //Then run your code
}
```